# php relationship key error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have several tables in mysql which are connected by a relation. Each has its own unique id and data. Only when trying to query them I get a strange result:

```
(use print_r)
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 
                       [0] => 1 
                       [tbl2_id] => 1 
                       [1] => 1 
                       [tbl3_id] => 1 
                       [2] => 1 
                       [3] => 1 
                       [name] => name1 
                       [4] => name1 
                       [surname] => ...
                     )
         )
```

I do not want the [0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSCs0.png) and so on.

Just for example, it should look like this:

```
 (use print_r)
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 
                        [tbl1_id] => 1 
                        [tbl2_id] => 1 
                        [tbl2_tbl1id] => 1 
                        [tbl3_id] => 1 
                        [tbl2_tbl1id] => 1  ...
                      )
       )
```

or something similar. I use PDO and when it invokes sql looks something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl` 
  INNER JOIN (tbl2, tbll) 
   ON tbl.tbl1_id=tbl1.id 
      AND tbl.tbl2_id=tbl2.id 
WHERE 1
```

after using it in mysql gets such an effect as in the picture(Run SQL query/queries on databas)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSCs0.png]

Comment: some few changes database but mainly it is a feed instead of id gave advice to write $row['tbl1.id'] or $row['tbl2.id'] and not in mysql displays me two times "id" and print_r displays as [0] or [1], and so on

Comment: Can you provide code to show how you query and get the result?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you are using PDOStatement::fetch()  with fetch_style set to **PDO::FETCH_BOTH** - which is default.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

use **PDO::FETCH_ASSOC** as the fetch_style, and you should get what you are looking for.

```
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: now works but not like I wanted, matter was I meant teeth remaining two versions of "id" or other tables such as "name" just to make they were discriminated because I have a user table in which you are "name" and I have a table tbl1 in which you are also "name" and by this one to me disappears. Is the only solution is to change the names of tables?

Comment: Then don't `SELECT *` - select only the fields you need.  You can also alias tables - `SELECT tb1.name FROM ...`

Comment: Upvote answer if "it works"  Your comment is a separate question.

Comment: and so all I have to write out ?? can not do it from a vending machine?

Comment: hahah :)

needs to get this effect as the PDO :: FETCH_NAMED so much would need something of this type
[Id] => Array
                (
                    [User] => 1
                    [Tbl1] => 1
                    [Tbl2] => 1
                )